# Can't Get Rid of Mac/Linux Malware or Hardware Bug

Tags: linux, mac, malware, bootloader, upnp

My MacBook now has a permanent back door for some hacker that I can't seem to get rid of. I even tried booting from a Linux USB stick, wiping everything including the EFI partition, but every time I try to reinstall my connection is hijacked by this "SlingShot" function and rerouted to some server hosting an infected install:

```
NetworkFinishOSRSHostInfoLookup: Resolved OSRS Hostname [osrecovery.apple.com] to 17.164.1.12, Port 80
GetStationAddressViaIpAgent: Client IP Address: 172.20.10.6
GetStationAddressViaIpAgent: Client Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.240
GetStationAddressViaIpAgent: Router IP Address: 172.20.10.1
GetStationAddressViaIpAgent: DnsServer 0 Address: 172.20.10.1
NetworkFinishOSRSHostInfoLookup: Resolved DNS Address on interface with address 172.20.10.6
NetworkFinishOSRSHostInfoLookup: Got 1 Network Interfaces.
NetworkFinishOSRSHostInfoLookup: Handle 0 was used for successful DNS resolution of OSRS.
SlingShot: Got OSRS Info: Hostname osrecovery.apple.com, Host IP 17.164.1.12, Port: 80
SlingShotSetupAuthParams: Got MLB SN 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
NetworkResolveDomainName: Resolved IP Address for 'oscdn.apple.com': 23.62.239.26
DownloadChunkedAsset: Downloading 44 chunks.
NetworkResolveDomainName: Resolved IP Address for 'oscdn.apple.com': 23.62.239.26
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: Recent download rate 0 dropped below 5 KBps, starting download stall timer.
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: 30 sec avg 0 KBps, 541 KBps new total, last total 0 KBps, now 270 KBps
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: Recent download rate 5 is above minimum 5 KBps, cancelling download stall timer.
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: 30 sec avg 24 KBps, 748 KBps new total, last total 934 KBps, now 841 KBps
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: 30 sec avg 23 KBps, 385 KBps new total, last total 429 KBps, now 407 KBps
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: 30 sec avg 24 KBps, 269 KBps new total, last total 286 KBps, now 277 KBps
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: 30 sec avg 57 KBps, 499 KBps new total, last total 446 KBps, now 472 KBps
SlingShotUpdateProgressUI: 30 sec avg 90 KBps, 645 KBps new total, last total 608 KBps, now 626 KBps
```

Booting from the Recovery HD or even from Apple's Network Recovery Drive still gets me stuck in this reroute, and a corrupted system is installed every time. Somehow this bug is able to authenticate on my system even after a wipe.

Seems to be hardware related though. Booting from Kali Linux on a USB stick I get these entries in the boot log showing a Mac firmware bug:

```
[    0.020231] [Firmware Bug]: ioapic 2 has no mapping iommu, interrupt remapping will be disabled
[    0.020291] Not enable interrupt remapping
[    0.020292] Failed to enable irq remapping.  You are vulnerable to irq-injection attacks.
```

Shortly followed by the system being posessed by interrupt signals from the network?

```
[    0.174491] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.174496] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S1_] (20140926/hwxface-580)
[    0.174499] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, While evaluating Sleep State [\_S2_] (20140926/hwxface-580)
[    0.174509] ACPI: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.174510] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.174530] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.180547] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.180552] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS assumes control of [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.180903] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-9a] only partially covers this bridge
```

Later on there are entries showing uPnP functions that seem to be masquerading as core audio files, and I've noticed the same thing happening with PulseAudio on my Linux laptop. And uPnP has been disabled on my router for a while now.

Also, every distro of Linux I've tried to download and install or install from a disk has been injected with this same vulnerability as well. Even if I go to a completely different network. So the bug is on my computer, but persists through a wipe. And every computer and router has been wiped and reinstalled from scratch, but it still gets into everything and I still have no control over my network connections.

Pretty sure this all started from my iPhone and access through the "Trust this Computer" authentication, but I haven't plugged my iPhone into either laptop since this started. And there are a lot more details and fun moments like an apache server being deployed 15 minutes after a wipe, my USB stick being deleted and the hub disabled as I tried to copy the server files as evidence, and AppleCare telling me that they see nothing particularly abnormal about any of this.

But... Assuming this is mainly in the boot config files, how do I clean those up on Mac and Linux to make sure it doesn't keep replicating itself? Or what should I do to lock things down?

Comment: What's corrupted about the system that gets installed after you do Internet Recovery? What makes you think the firmware bug that the Linux installer reports is anything more than just a typical programmer error firmware bug or missing feature? That is, why do you think it's corrupted/hacked/hijacked firmware? And what in the third log snippet you posted makes you think you're getting interrupts from the network?

Answer (score 6):

I think you've worked yourself into a paranoid tizzy by taking the worst possible interpretation of a bunch of log messages you don't really understand.

I'm pretty sure SlingShot is Apple's internal name for what's publicly known as "OS X Internet Recovery". If your Mac's hard drive has been completely erased (not even the normally-hidden recovery partition exists), then your Mac will try to netboot off of an Apple server (possibly hosted on an Akamai/EdgeSuite CDN server; Apple's long used Akamai as their favorite CDN).

This article gives you some information on Internet Recovery (as well as local hard drive recovery partition recovery): https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4718

I think the "Firmware Bug" the Linux installer is reporting is either just a bug, or an overzealous installer calling it a "bug" when the firmware just doesn't have a particular security feature the installer was hoping it would have. I don't see any evidence of this being a corrupted, hacked, or hijacked firmware image.

As for the last log snippet, please realize that motherboards often have "bridge chips" to connect one bus to another (like connecting two PCI busses to each other), and "interrupt routing" refers to the route from chip-to-chip that interrupt signals take across the motherboard. This "bridging" and "routing" is all about chips and busses and other electronics circuits on the motherboard, not LAN/Internet networking.

Comment: I have more complete logs but they are too long to include. How would I post those? But I can also say that the Apple guy I talked to was unaware of the Akamai server deal, and after the first time I downloaded the reinstall that way I found log files showing subsequent downloads of Gatekeeper configurations files, Remote Access setup files, and Chinese language support. This was all while I was asleep. A lot of other things like that. And I have Wireshark logs showing all sorts of abnormal behavior too with IP addresses I don't recognize flying around when I'm sitting here doing nothing.

Comment: Also please understand that before two weeks ago I knew nothing about any Linux or boot processes or routing. I've tried to give myself a crash course in all of it in the past couple of weeks, and have done everything I know how on my own to troubleshoot this in addition to dealing with Apple tech support. I can't explain what is wrong very well because I don't know and I don't know which of the millions of lines of logs are relevant... But I have been paying attention to the logs for years. Definitely long enough to know that a LOT of things are there that aren't normal.

Comment: You can post long texts to gist.github.com or pastebin.com, and then link to it from your post. If you run afoul of the limits on the number of links new users can make, consider entering the URL as text without making it a link. Gatekeeper, Remote Access, and Chinese language files are all names for things in a standard OS X install. Modern OSes have lots of background processes that talk to lots of servers and CDNs, so you'll always see lots of IP addresses you don't recognize; don't freak out unit you've done hostname lookups on those IPs and made sure they're not Apple or Akamai.

Comment: Overall, I think you should just focus on whatever it was you were originally trying to do (get Linux installed, get OS X reinstalled, or whatever your goal was), and write up separate Questions if you need help with that. Nothing you've shared so far looks suspicious in the least. Putting aside the log messages you don't understand, is there anything actually wrong with your machine? Are you having any actual problems?

Answer (score 0):

It's either an integral part of the network you are on, or your router has been compromised and had it's DNS played with.